# Rotating a 3D coordinate

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, kinect-sdk

I need to rotate a single coordinate in WPF - C#.

The values `x, y,z` stored in `GeometryModel3D[]` points.

For example, coordinate(x, y, z) rotate at speficic-axis.

[UPDATE] Rotation transformation using quaternion. The problem are I don't get the new vector value and when I view the pointcloud, It seem drag away in Meshlab.

```
Matrix3D m = Matrix3D.Identity;
Quaternion q = new Quaternion(new Vector3D(320 / 2, y, maxDepth - minDepth), 90);
m.Rotate(q);
Vector3D myVectorToRotate = new Vector3D(((TranslateTransform3D)points[i].Transform).OffsetX,                        ((TranslateTransform3D)points[i].Transform).OffsetY,     ((TranslateTransform3D)points[i].Transform).OffsetZ);

m.Transform(myVectorToRotate);
pointcloud.Add(new Point3D(myVectorToRotate.X,myVectorToRotate.Y,myVectorToRotate.Z));
```

I'm still can't get the correct value transformation.

I want to apply rotation transformation for 2nd point cloud scanned from kinect. Since the 1st scan data don't involved rotation, the code for capture data and usage is like below:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 240; y += resolution)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 320; x += resolution)
    {
        if (((TranslateTransform3D)points[i].Transform).OffsetZ >= minDepth
              && ((TranslateTransform3D)points[i].Transform).OffsetZ <= maxDepth)
        {
            pointcloud.Add(new Point3D(((TranslateTransform3D)points[i].Transform).OffsetX,                                                        ((TranslateTransform3D)points[i].Transform).OffsetY,                                              ((TranslateTransform3D)points[i].Transform).OffsetZ));
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The example is to rotate a point by 90 degrees around the y axis?

Comment: Yes, but the code i showed seem wrong because I don't how to set the matrix..

Comment: [link]Matrix3D Structure(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.matrix3d(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Have you looked into [RotateTransform3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.rotatetransform3d.aspx)?

Comment: already look but I got error because changing `GeometryModel3D` from `TranslateTransform3D` into `RotateTransform3D`.

Comment: [This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23332/WPF-3D-Primer) should be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Create any kind of matrix. For example a [rotation matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.rotate.aspx) and then use the static method [Vector.Multiply(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms599350.aspx) 
See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645571/wpf-rotate-a-2d-vector) and the [MSDN general transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx) overview.

Examples for Vector3D:

1. [3D transformation WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274742/3d-transformation-wpf)
2. [Rotate a vector by quaternion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/080b45d1-f29b-415b-b1d6-39173185c0f1)

   ```
   Vector3D v = new Vector3D(1.0, -1.0, 2.0);
   ...
   AxisAngleRotation3D axisAngle = new AxisAngleRotation3D(axis, angle);
   RotateTransform3D myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform3D(axisAngle, centerVector);
   v.Multiply(myRotateTransform);
   ```

Comment: sorry, i still don't understand how to achieve the rotation using rotation matrix. Hope you can help by simple code :).

Comment: @akuhero, did you look at the stackoverflow link given by Matthias? There is a simple code sample over there

Comment: @sinelaw, I did look but how to apply to a 3D vector?

Comment: that why I can't solve it. I don't know how to form Matrix3D structure

Comment: The links above are a good starting point. But I will edit and add some more links to Vector3D examples. But cool, that you are giving a down-vote instead of providing an answer.

Comment: it's a good start (can not be denied). Tq for your feeds. Hope hear something from you soon.

Comment: @Matthias actually I didn't downvote - in fact I upvoted (PS deleted my previous comment since I see you've added 3D-related stuff)

Comment: tq for update. When using quaternion, I don't know how to get the new point. [updated in question]

Comment: Based on your example, I got an error at `Multiply` function.